# How to generate Charts in SubReport in ReportViewer C#

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, reportviewer

I'm currently developing a WPF Application and I use ReportViewer that contains one chart but I need to display another chart in my report. I create a subreport and call it in my main report. But if I insert a chart in subreport doesn't works!
`The Subreport1 could not be found at the specified location. Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.`
If I use a table or textbox it works but not if a charts.
This is my code Behind:

```
private void showReport(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            RVInfoGrafico.Reset();
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(MSubreportProcessingEventHandler);

            DataTable dt = GetData2();
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Project.Info.rdlc";
            RVInfoGrafico.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            RVInfoGrafico.RefreshReport();

        }
        void MSubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt9 = GetData4();
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",dt9));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states it can't find Subreport1. Maybe try providing it directly using LoadSubreportDefinition("Subreport1", xxx)?

Something like this:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("RVInfoGrafico.Reports.Subreport.rdlc"); // Change to your path or get a stream of it some other way
RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("Subreport1", stream);
```

FYI - In a project I've done this in, the .rdlc files' Build Action in VisualStudio was set to "Embedded Resource".